# Reporting Service Formula show #Error on Server

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

When I update my code from visual studio 2008 to visual studio 2012, all reporting service reports (client site reports) working on my local and my co-workers machine. But after I deploy all reports to the server.

All reports formula show #Error, no formula part show correctly.

I think may server missing some dll, and I don't have any idea now.
ex.

```
= Iif(IsDate(Fields!ReceivedDate.Value),Format(Fields!ReceivedDate.Value,"MMM dd, yyyy"),"")

="For the period between " & Format(Parameters!StartDate.Value,"MMM dd,yyyy") & " and " & Format(Parameters!EndDate.Value,"MMM dd,yyyy")
= "% of applications completed in 10 days or less = " & IIF(COUNTROWS()=0,0, FORMAT(COUNT(IIF(Fields!NumberOfDays.Value<10,1,NOTHING))/COUNTROWS(),"P2"))
```

Thanks in advance!

Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is came from the security when I update reports from visual studio  2008 to visual studio 2012. after do some research, I found solution as follow:

```
<system.web>
  <trust legacyCasModel="true" level="Full"/>
</system.web>
```

visit http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/be1a6149-a120-4e66-96f8-63f5c4d43c87/error-using-any-builtin-fields?forum=vsreportcontrols

and [ReportViewer 2010 fails to evaluate expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347125/reportviewer-2010-fails-to-evaluate-expressions)

Hopes it can help people who update there project from visual studio 2008 to visual studio 2010 or visual studio 2012.